# Button Next and Previous in carousel not working , when two carousel in one page.?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'Have two carousel in one page.

in first carousel is working,
but in second carousel using multiple item carousel isn't not working button next and prev..

becase the class name for next and preview is same beetwen carousel one and second
this is my code in second multiple carousel

//this in first carousel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPSuF.png)

//this is second carousel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQXrd.png)

thankyou, i hope in here can found solution.
Regards,
Genda